# Nuxt Compostion API: Change class on hover

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

```
<script setup>

import Logo from "../assets/svgs/Logo";
import Menu from "../assets/svgs/Menu";

const hover = Boolean
let boxTop

if (hover === true) {
  boxTop = 'boxTop--0'
} else {
  boxTop = 'boxTop--20'
}

</script>

<template>
  <nav class=" w-full fixed flex items-center">
    <div class="w-full flex h-full">
      <div class="px-6 flex items-center justify-center h-full relative "
           @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseleave="hover = false"
      >
        <Menu class="w-10 fill-white"/>

        <div class="absolute w-full h-full bg-black" :style="boxTop"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

I want to make it so when the mouse enters the div, the css class "boxTop--0" gets added, and, when the mouse leaves the div, the css class "boxTop--20" gets added. However, I can't figure out how to do it with compositon api.

I would be very greatful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at following snippet:
You can create reactive state (`boxTop`) with `ref` and create function for changing state.

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: "#demo",
  setup() {
    const boxTop = ref(null)
    const hover = (val) => {
      if (val) {
        boxTop.value = 'boxTop--0'
      } else {
        boxTop.value = 'boxTop--20'
      }
    }
    return { boxTop, hover }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <nav class=" w-full fixed flex items-center">
    <div class="w-full flex h-full">
      <div class="px-6 flex items-center justify-center h-full relative "
           @mouseenter="hover(true)" @mouseleave="hover(false)"
      >
        hover me
        <div class="absolute w-full h-full bg-black" :style="boxTop">
        {{ boxTop }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick, using a `computed`.

```html
<script setup>
import Menu from "../assets/svgs/Menu"

const hover = ref(true)
const boxTop = computed(() => hover.value ? 'boxTop--0' : 'boxTop--20')
</script>

<template>
  <nav class="fixed flex items-center w-full">
    <div class="flex w-full h-full">
      <div class="relative flex items-center justify-center h-24 h-full px-6 bg-green-500" @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseleave="hover = false">
        <Menu class="w-10 fill-white" />

        <div class="absolute w-full h-full bg-black" :class="boxTop"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<style scoped>
.boxTop--0 {
  background-color: red;
}
.boxTop--20 {
  background-color: teal;
}
</style>
```

I've used `:class="boxTop"` and some classes to help me debug what you have tried.